# PODIO API: Get list of organization workspaces

Tags: php, ruby, api, podio

I'm working with the API, and no one I hire knows how to make the API call that gets a list of organization workspaces.

It's extremely frustrating. Can you please take a moment and let me know how to actually make the PHP or Ruby call? I've already tried hiring people, and I'm waisting money.

Please help.

https://developers.podio.com/doc/spaces/get-list-of-organization-workspaces-238875316

Answer (score 1):

The call is actually quite simple: `GET /space/org/{org_id}/available/`

As Chris mentioned, you can do that using any of our SDKs, e.g.:

**PHP**

```
PodioSpace.phpPodioSpace::get_available( $org_id );
```

**Ruby**

```
Podio::Space.find_open_for_org( org_id )
```

You an find the docs here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/spaces/get-available-spaces-1911961

Comment: Thanks @domokun This helps for open spaces, but doesn't return all spaces (e.g. private). This only returns open ones.

Answer (score 0):

Podio provides client libraries for both PHP and Ruby, as well as a few other languages.

PHP: https://github.com/podio/podio-php

Ruby: https://github.com/podio/podio-rb

There are examples in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Chris. This helps for open spaces, but doesn't return all space (e.g. private). This only returns open spaces.